# NSSet from attributes of objects (performance)

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, nsset

I am trying to create a `NSSet` of strings collected from an unknown (possibly large) number of objects' attributes.

The user of my app logs objects during the month - they have different attributes wheras i am only interested in the `NSString *category` name.

```
Object.h
NSString *category
...
```

During a month he may log between 10 and 1000 such objects, stored in coredata. The user can define own categories - and i have to find out which categories were used during that month (to create an export file).

Currently i do the following (pseudocode)

```
NSArray *allObjects = [_dataHandler fetchAllObjectsForMonth:monthToExport];
NSMutableSet *allCategoryNamesSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];
for(Object *obj in allObjects){
    [allCategoryNamesSet addObject:obj.category];
}
```

Wheras this works, it gets really slow with a lot of objects as the fetching takes time and the iterating as well of course.

I have tried something like that as well:

```
NSArray *categories = [allObjects valueForKeyPath:@"category"];
NSSet *allCategorieNamesSet = [NSSet initWithArray:categories];
```

maybe i did something wrong but it didnt quite work :/

What i am interested in is, if there is a solution that could significantly speed up this process? something i might have overlooked.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there any issue with `NSMutableSet *allCategoryNamesSet=[NSMutableSet setWithArray:allObjects];`?

Comment: yes. then i would get a Set consisting of Objects instead of the category attributes of the Objects. i need a set of all category names that were used during the month :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested only in the (distinct) value of the `category` attribute, set

```
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"category"]];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
```

for your fetch request. The fetch request then return an array of dictionaries (instead of managed objects) containing the `category` values.

The advantage is that this "filtering" is done on the SQLite level. One disadvantage (or "caveat") is that this implies `setIncludesPendingChanges:NO`, i.e. the fetch request is done only against the saved database and does not include unsaved pending modifications.

Comment: Actually this is all i am interested in! a will give it a go this afternoon, but this looks very very promising! big +1 and probably an accept later today :)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord), which is a convenience library for working with Core Data. This should help you do a lot of these tasks.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for this link! i will use it in future projects for sure. The app is already in the appstore so i will not go and change the coredata setup anymore. The question is meant for an new version of the project. but +1 for the great hint :)